# Seagull simulator : How to send AVP 'Originator-SCCP-Address' in E-164 encoding format in diameter request?

Tags: diameter-protocol

Network is sending AVP 'Originator-SCCP-Address' in E-164 encoding format and we are able to parse it properly.

In Seagull dictionary, this AVP is defined as :

```
<define name="Originator-SCCP-Address" type="OctetString">
  <setfield name="avp-code" value="2008"> </setfield>
  <setfield name="flags" value="192"> </setfield>
  <setfield name="Vendor-ID" value="10415"> </setfield>
</define>
```

And our code is unable to parse it as input value is being treated like a String, instead of encoded address AVP.

Answer (score 0):

[PCAP from network showing Originator-SCCP-Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SPsb.jpg)

For sending a value 'Originator-SCCP-Address Address: 359898000135' , we have to send AVP value = 0x0008333539383938303030313335

First four characters indicate the Address Family 8 (E-164) encoding and rest of the characters are encoded as the address value.